# AWS API >> How can I make one method public and keep the rest authenticated with API Key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3

So I'm new to AWS API's and I'm trying to do something very straightforward but I'm struggling with how to approach it.

So I have an AWS API like so

[image: picture of API tree]
The authentication for each request is API KEY.
However, this S3 only holds images that I would like to be able to serve without an API Key. So basically I would like to make GET requests public and leave everything else alone.

When I go in and change the 3 GET requests to require no authorization, I get this:[image: view of error message] on each one.

I'm totally lost. I am an application dev and this is out of my scope.
Any idea, even conceptually, about how I should go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's just a warning, letting you know an API key isn't required for that endpoint, even though an API key is configured for this API Gateway.

It's like all those warnings you get when you make an S3 bucket public. Amazon just wants to make sure you realize you are making something public.